# Creating Object From Class That Object is in

Tags: java, object, static

```
public class MultipleObjects2Test {

    static int a;
    static int b;

    MultipleObjects2Test(int a,int b){

        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;}

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            MultipleObjects2Test test = new MultipleObjects2Test(5,10);
            MultipleObjects2Test test1 = new MultipleObjects2Test(15,20);


        System.out.print(test.a);
        System.out.print(test.b);

        System.out.print(test1.a);
        System.out.print(test1.b);

    }
}
```

I think,output is 5,10,15,20 respectively.But the code works as 15 20 15 20.

Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 2):

Your members are static :

```
static int a;
static int b;
```

Therefore both instances have the same value for `a` and `b`.

Remove the `static` keyword and you'll get your expected output.

```
public class MultipleObjects2Test 
{
    int a;
    int b;

    MultipleObjects2Test(int a,int b)
    {
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        MultipleObjects2Test test = new MultipleObjects2Test(5,10);
        MultipleObjects2Test test1 = new MultipleObjects2Test(15,20);

        System.out.print(test.a);
        System.out.print(test.b);

        System.out.print(test1.a);
        System.out.print(test1.b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`a` and `b` are declared as static which mean [class variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html), change

```
static int a;static int b;
```

to

```
 int a; int b;
```